# How to copy table having CLOB column from one user to another in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have group of tables which should be copied from one user to another user. I wrote a procedure which copies all the tables when I run it. One of the table has CLOB column which shows error when I run the procedure.

I tried

```
insert into destination_table_name values(select colume_name from source_table_name);
```

But the table has 20 columns so above one cannot be used. Kindly help me to fix the error.

The actual error message is:

```
"**ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables**"
```

Comment: Kindly tell us what the error is, and the code causing it.

Comment: Did you try along `CREATE TABLE OtherSchema.TableCopy AS SELECT * FROM OriginalSchema.OriginalTable;`?

Comment: Actually the table already exists in Other Schema I just need to copy the data. So I didnot try CREATE TABLE

Comment: Well - you could still drop the table and then start over. Otherwise, follow the horse's with no name advise. Or add more detail, if you still need assistance. - Whichever works best for you.

Comment: @OldProgrammer "ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables" is my error.

Comment: @MathuMathi That error message is *essential* to your question. Please update your question accordingly (by using the "Edit" button) instead of posting additional information in comments

Comment: And please update the *real* query you are using. The one that you have there is invalid and would not run at all. Plus it doesn't use a DBLink so it also will never throw the `ORA-22992` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a select as the source for an `insert` you must not specify the `values` clause, which is [clearly documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#i2111652) You should also always specify the columns you want the insert to affect:

```
insert into destination_table_name (column_1, column_2, column3_)
select colume_1, column_2_column_3 
from source_table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the whole table (data) anyway, the most straightforward way seems to be:

```
CREATE TABLE OtherSchema.TableCopy AS
  SELECT * FROM OriginalSchema.OriginalTable
;
```

#### Update

Your comment

> "ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables" is my
>   error.

changes the picture completely. The error message reflects on this not to be feasible 'by design'.

A few workarounds have been suggested:

- `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ... AS SELECT * FROM <TABLE>@dbLink` on the target machine. Source: [user500315 Feb 8, 2007 9:28 AM  response to "ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables"](https://community.oracle.com/thread/471047#thread-message-1683314).
- `CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE` on the target machine. `INSERT ... SELECT` into this temporary table the `CLOB` column from the remote database. And proceed from there. Source: ["How to select table from remote database having clob field"](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:950029833940) @ Ask Tom.
- Use a cursor. Source: [659137 May 11, 2009 6:51 PM response to "DBLink problem ORA-22992"](https://community.oracle.com/thread/319043#discussion-3463967).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.